# Extracting tables from a DOCX Word document in python

Tags: python, xpath, ms-word, docx

I'm trying to extract a content of tables in DOCX Word document, and boy I'm new to xml/xpath.

```
from docx import *
document = opendocx('someFile.docx')
tableList = document.xpath('/w:tbl')
```

This triggers "XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix" error. I'm sure it's just the first one to expect while developing the script. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a tutorial for [python-docx](http://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

Could you kindly provide an example of table extraction?

Comment: Where did you get docx ? Can you provide an URL?

Comment: You should look for a python xml tutorial. The opendocx function returns an xml document, according to the source. The rest of the functions in the python-docx library are wrappers around the lxml python library, at http://lxml.de/ or so it seems to me.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: The following code doesn't raise error, but strangely yields []
    `tableList = document.xpath('//tbl')`
    `print tableList`
Is this some DOCX feature that I don't understand?

Comment: @mgierdal that looks like a correct result. It's searching through the xml tree for tbl and not finding it. So, your result set is empty. I'd suggest `print document` to get out your entire xml and see if you actually have the tag you expect. If so, then your function call is incorrect in some way. Find the docs on the xpath function in the lxml library, and see if you've got a malformed command.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: Printing with `print etree.tostring(document)` shows <w:tbl> tags. I also tried `'/tbl'` (yields empty, too) and either form with an extra argument `namespaces=document.nsmap` to no avail. I found that it's prepending with a namespace shorthand 'w' what's offensive.

Comment: @mgierdal http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method it looks like there are some special details for namespace stuff. Look down the page in the link for passing a namespaces dictionary, and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: Yes! At last try I married prepending with explicit DOCX namespaces dictionary (always included in DOCX) `tblList = document.xpath('//w:tbl', namespaces=document.nsmap)`. Works like a dream. So, as I understand it **w:** is a shorthand that has to be expanded to the full namespace name, and the dictionary for that is provided by **document.nsmap**. Thanks for your patient guidance!

Comment: @mgierdal I'll add that in as an answer to the question then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back and forth, we found out that a namespace was needed for this to work correctly. The xpath method is the appropriate solution, it just needs to have the document namespace passed in first.

The [lxml xpath method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) has the details for namespace stuff. Look down the page in the link for passing a namespaces dictionary, and other details.

As explained by mgierdal in his comment above:

> tblList = document.xpath('//w:tbl', namespaces=document.nsmap) works
>   like a dream. So, as I understand it w: is a shorthand that has to be
>   expanded to the full namespace name, and the dictionary for that is
>   provided by document.nsmap.

Answer (score 1):

First install `python-docx` as mentioned by @abdulsaboor

```
pip install python-docx
```

Then this code should do:

```
from docx import Document


document = Document('myfile.docx')

for table in document.tables:
    print()
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the table from docx using python-docx. Check the following code:

```
from docx import Document()
document = Document(file_path)

tables = document.tables
```