# how do I extract tables from Microsoft Word in linux?

Tags: python, ms-word

how do I extract tables from Microsoft Word in linux?

or at least, is there any way that I can extract the text with *original layout*?

Thanks

Comment: extrac it to what? what kind of object do you need in Python? string, list?

Comment: I believe someone else recently asked this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097631/extracting-tables-from-a-docx-word-document-in-python