# How to copy all table with python-docx?

Tags: python, copy, docx, xlsx

I use the `python-docx` library and I have a document named `file.docx`. I need to copy all the content of the `.docx` tables to `file.xlsx`

My code is

```
from docx import *
f = open('file.docx')
d = Document(f)
ts = d.tables[1]
print ts
<docx.table.Table object at 0xb691f7ac>
```

However, `<docx.table.Table object at 0xb691f7ac>` does not contain the content. How can I get the contents of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, where I had to generate a multipage document where each page had the same table, but with different content in it.

I proceeded like this:

```
def _combine_docx(documents):
    '''
    Takes a list of docx.Documents and performs a deepcopy on the
    first table in each document and adds the copies successively to
    the first document in the list.
   '''
if not documents or len(documents) == 0:
    return docx.Document()
if len(documents) == 1:
    return documents[0]

merged_document = documents[0]
p = merged_document.paragraphs[0]
for doc in documents[1:]:
    doc_table = doc.tables[0]

    new_tbl = deepcopy(doc_table._tbl)
    p._p.addnext(new_tbl)

return merged_document
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try the following:

```
from docx import *
f = open('file.docx')
document = Document(f)
tableList=document.xpath('//w:tbl', namespaces=document.nsmap)
print tableList
```

Inspired from [Extracting tables from a DOCX Word document in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097631/extracting-tables-from-a-docx-word-document-in-python?rq=1)